# Delegatecall in a view function

Tags: solidity

I am using the proxy-delegate pattern for my Solidity smart contract. In the proxy contract, I have a function

```
function getVariable() view returns(uint256) {
    delegateContract.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature(
                "getVariable()"
            )
    )
}
```

In the delegate contract, the getVariable is also a view function. However, I receive an error when trying to compile, saying it is not possible to use delgatecall in a view function, because a delegatecall might alter the state of the contract. If that's the case, what is the alternative to a delegatecall in a view / getter function?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to rely on the fallback function's delegatecall for that specific function call ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do it both ways.  Either just specify what you want this function to return, or just delete this function and use the fallback to delegate call:

```
fallback() external payable {
    delegateContract.delegatecall(msg.data);
}
```

Then when you call getVariables on your contract it will just read from your delegateContract.

Comment: Hey, what do you mean with "Either just specify what you want this function to return", as I am using a upgradeable contract I prefer not to use the fallback() function, what would then be the other alternative to preserve state visibility when using a delegate.call to a view function?